# check_plain() error when used with variable_get()

Tags: emails

I'm incorporating email notifications into a custom Drupal 7 module, and I'm using the following code for `hook_mail()`.

```
$subject_template = variable_get('pto_notification_subject', PTO_NOTIFICATION_SUBJECT);
$message['subject'] = t(check_plain($subject_template), $params, array('langcode' => $langcode));
$body_template = variable_get('pto_notification_body', PTO_NOTIFICATION_BODY);
$message['body'][] = t(filter_xss($body_template), $params, array('langcode' => $langcode));
```

When I do that, I get this error:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /var/www/mysite.dev/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>   Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /var/www/mysite.dev/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>   Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

If I print the value of `$subject_template` and `$body_template`, I see strings, not an arrays.  Using `is_array()` on both confirms that as well. Any idea why `check_plain()` could be reading those variables as arrays?

I also tried the following code, but I am still getting the same error.

```
function pto_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $langcode = $message['language']->language;
  $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
  if (!module_exists('mimemail')){
    $message['headers']['Mime-Version'] = '1.0';
  }
  switch ($key) {
    case 'request':
      $subject_template = variable_get('pto_notification_subject', PTO_NOTIFICATION_SUBJECT);
      $message['subject'] = t($subject_template, $params, array('langcode' => $langcode));
      $body_template = variable_get('pto_notification_body', PTO_NOTIFICATION_BODY);
      $message['body'][] = t($body_template, $params, array('langcode' => $langcode));
      break;
  }
}
```

Here's the result of print_r($params):

```
Array
(
    [!request_user_name] => Information Technology
    [!request_pto_type] => PTO
    [!request_amount] => 8.00
    [!request_date_range] => 7/13/2016
    [!request_reason] => Testing....again.
    [!request_submitted] => 7/19/2016
    [!site_url] => http://mysite.dev
    [!site_name] => My Site
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Cc] => me@myemail.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Assuming you have a standard/working version of PHP, the only possible answer is that `$subject_template` is an array. Or maybe a class that implements `__toString` and `ArrayAccess`. It's not a string, anyway

Comment: And, of course, assuming that your call to `check_plain($subject_template)` is actually what's causing the problem. Placeholders for `t()` are also run through `check_plain`, so you're kind of doubling up there anyway, and it might not be your explicit line that's causing the problem. What's `$langcode`? Maybe an array?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, it appears that t() only runs through check_plain() if using @parameters, not !parameters, which is what I'm using. (https://api.drupal.org/comment/25348#comment-25348) either way, I updated the post with some new code to remove the duplicate check_plain() and the problem persists.

Comment: Also, it is perfectly useless to pass a dynamic string to `t()`; it will be never translated.

Comment: It is likely that you are triggering this error from another place. To debug that, go to line 1571 in bootstrap.inc and add an if condition to check is_array on the argument and use debug_backtrace() to see what is the source of the problem.

Comment: We need to see with which values is initialized `$params`. Without that, we cannot answer.

Comment: @anoopjohn Now I'm more confused -- I added if (is_array($text)) and there was nothing that reported true at all, despite throwing the same error. I also added the dump of $params to the original post.

Comment: Not sure how is_array($text) cannot return true when the next line triggers the error that $text is an array. What did you try to do inside the if condition? You will have to do a watchdog call in there to really catch it. If I can get access to your set up I can take a look.

Comment: Watchdog is logging the warning but it seems to be the same error message that I posted above - it's not logging what specifically was in the $text parameter.

Comment: Ahh, I found it -- it was the CC array that was causing the problem.  After adding the CC array to the $message['headers'] array I unset it from $params and all is well.  If you can post an answer I'm happy to credit you for it - it was the watchdog debugging that got me going.